# AChartEngine - How to get Multiple Y values for "single Date" value(as X axis) in single series?

Tags: android, graph, charts, achartengine

I am getting problem like this:
http://prntscr.com/3nng06

[image]

How can I remove that multiple dates? 
I have used TimeChartView & Time Series in this chart.
Any kind of help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I was also facing the same problem while using it..what I did was that I would sort the data as per dates first. After that combine the points which were on the same data and create a new series and then add all the points in this new series to the dataset that we are showing.

Comment: combine the point means you want me to make it one Y value from many? Will you plz elaborate your answer?

Comment: yes that is what I meant..but this solution depends on what kind of data is shown using the graph.

Comment: My problem was to must show Multiple Y values for single Date. There's not an issue for showing a single Y value.

Comment: what I meant was that the quantity that you are going to show,if combined the values should make sense. If you can show one value then there is no problem.

Comment: If I combine the values of Y then how will it be shown to multiple points in Chart for single X value?

Answer (score 1):

I have solved the problem by :

```
mSetRenderer.setXAxisMin(Starting_date.getTime());
mSetRenderer.setXAxisMax(Ending_date.getTime());    
mSetRenderer.setXLabels(0);
mSetRenderer.addXTextLabel(dates.get(i).getTime(), stringFormatOfDate));
```